# Bash using sed with argument - as a script works, as a function in .bashrc doesn't

Tags: bash, sed, arguments

This line of code works as intended when pasted in a text file and run with bash:

```
ps -ef | sed -n -e '1p' -e "/$1/p"
```

(It finds the process matching the argument string and prints it with a header)

The same line used in a function inside .bashrc doesn't work:

```
function fproc {
    ps -ef | sed -n -e '1p' -e "/$1/p"
}
```

(If given argument x it complains:

```
$ fproc x
sed: can't read x: No such file or directory
```

Can someone explain why? Thanks.

Comment: This works for me.  Are you sure you're actually loading/reloading `.bashrc` in your test?  How about: `source ~/.bashrc; fproc x`?

Comment: I did reload .bashrc. But after reading that it worked for you I tried it on konsole and it works. It just doesn't work in guake (0.4.2-7). Thanks.

Comment: why do you use double sed? you already chose first line using 1p

Comment: not a double sed, first action print header, second print the process info but it can be consolidated with a `-e "1p;/$1/p"`